# use div as paragraph

Tags: css, html

I am trying to use my `<div>` element as `<p>` a element.
The HTML doesn't allow this and when I try to use `<p>` inside `<p>` or `<h1>` inside `<p>` I got
my `<p>` wrapper closed. (something like this `<p></p><h1>blah</h1>`)

I need that my `<div>` get the same behavior of my `<p>` tag.

Can I do this using css style?

[UPDATE]

Just to explain, I need to do this because I am using tinymce and abcpdf.. the rendered pdf over the html has problems when text is rendered inside div. 
I think that default values of the parent (in this case, the `<div>`), get over not assigneds properties.

[/UPDATE]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yup, definitely. Just note down the properties you want in the `div` and put them in a css class, add the class name to the `div`. After all `div` is the mother of all elements, a generic container in other words

Comment: Why do you want to put a paragraph within a paragraph? Or a header within a paragraph? `p`s are meant to contain regular text. The wording of your question is very confusing.

Comment: explain first why you want do it, to provide for you a better solution.

Comment: what do you wanna achieve with this?

Comment: Your title and update say you want to treat a `div` as a `p`, but your example seems to want to treat a `p` as a `div`. So which is it?

Comment: @Martha.. My example is what I am doing right now, but without the expected result.
If you know a way to make a `div` has the same behavior of a `p`.. please, tell me.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with this?  Your example and question wording are not very clear. Can you provide an example of the html you are currently working with and tell us where you think the error is (instead of writing out an abstract explanation as you have already done)?

Comment: The question was really simple.. there's only one line that explains what I need: `I need that my <div> get the same behavior of my <p> tag.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use

```
<span>
```

instead

```
<div>
```

The  tag is used to group inline-elements in a document.

The  tag provides no visual change by itself.

The  tag provides a way to add a hook to a part of a text or a part of a document.

References:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_span